# Installing new basement post to support first floor post

Tags: basement, structural, load-bearing, beam, post

I am opening a first floor load bearing wall 15 feet wide . This wall sits one foot off from the basement center steel beam, with 2x10 joists 16" on center.

The engineer has specified the first floor posts are to be 3 2x6's. One of the posts will sit on top of the sub-floor and a single 2x10  floor joist. A basement steel column will be installed below.

What is the best way to add support to the single 2x10 ? Is sistering 2 short pieces of 2x10 and blocking to adjacent 2x10's adequate ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why would a joist that's supported by a column need additional reinforcement? Please provide diagrams or photos. It's a bit difficult to compile all those words into a complete scene.

Comment: Also, if an engineer is involved why aren't they providing this information?

Comment: The engineer should be guiding you on any added support required in the basement and **any footing needs.**  A basement floor slab is not intended to carry large point loads.  If you were to add a column in the basement you might also need to add a footing underneath that new column.